# How to get sum of values in days intervals using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery. First one `t` contains creating dates for each id. Second table `t0` contains profit records day by day for each id.
I want to get columns with sums of profit for first and second 30 days for each id as well as for the first day.

```
SELECT t.created_at, t.id, sum(t1.profit) profit_1_week, sum(t2.profit) profit_2_week, sum(t3.profit) profit_1_day FROM t
LEFT JOIN t0 t1 ON t.id = t.id AND t1.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
LEFT JOIN t0 t2 ON t.id = t.id AND t2.inport_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
LEFT JOIN t0 t3 ON t.id = t.id AND t3.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY t.created_at, t.id
ORDER BY t.created_at
```

This code runs but sums are wrong because sum of the first day much more then monthly. Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `if`:

```
SELECT t.created_at, t.id,
  sum(if(t0.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY), t0.profit, 0)) profit_1_week,
  sum(if(t0.inport_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 60 DAY), t0.profit, 0)) profit_2_week,
  sum(if(t0.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY), t0.profit, 0)) profit_1_day 
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t0 ON t.id = t0.id
GROUP BY t.created_at, t.id
ORDER BY t.created_at
```